# "Fortinet SSL-VPN Client plugin is not installed on your computer" when using Firefox 22+ to access FortiGate site

Tags: firefox, ssl, vpn

I do have the FortiGate client installed and it is not disabled. It worked until I upgraded Firefox to version 22. How do I get this to work with the new version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This a known bug related to Firefox issue. SSl vpn client plugin's would not work if you are running Firefox version higher then 20 Reference to bug id (0211153).The purposed workaround at this time would be to download stand alone sll vpn client.Please see the link given below for downloading stand alone ssl vpn or go back on a previous version (like 21)

Download SslvpnClient.msi from http://dekiwiki.ties2.net/Fortinet/Fortinet_SSL_VPN_Client_Installers

Comment: Is this bug already fixed? I can't find any info related to bug id (0211153). Is this Firefox bug id, or Fortinet bug id?

Comment: Still a thing on Windows 7 and Firefox 48.0.2 (2016-09). The above is a verbatim copy of the answer by "Auns Yasin Fortinet TAC Engineer". It does not reference Mozilla [Bug 211153: " xpcom_compat.dll was not found"](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=211153), which  has nothing to do with it but FortiNet bug 211153 (not available on the Internet and my support subscription has expired). See [Mozilla question 963538](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/963538). FortiGate thus bumps this to Mozilla, which may or may not be justified (they may be using ActiveX for all we know).

Comment: A commenter on the discussion thread of [Mozilla question 963538](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/963538) says to add the FortiGate website to the ["Compatibility View Settings"](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2536204) found in Internet Explorer (CogwheelTopRight > Compatibility View Settings). I tried that but no joy. It was a long shot because I don't see what would be the relation at all.

Comment: But note that this is not a real problem as the downloaded and executed installer has left the "FortiClient SSLVPN" application in the Start Menu, and it works as expected.